# Generating Excel file by using LoadFromCollection from a JSON object

Tags: c#, json, list

I need to produce excel sheet from JSON object. 
My JSON object is unknown and can be different from call to call. It have a simple structure (same fields in multiple rows).

I want to use the following code.

```
workSheet.Cells[2, 1].LoadFromCollection(dataList, false);
```

*dataList* input is List  (dynamic)

Since my JSON is unknown, I can't define a class for this list (params names and types)

My question is **How do I convert a JSON object dynamically to List?**

for example I have json object with 3 rows to export:

```
dataJson -> [{"FirstName":"Yaniv","LastName":"Test","Age": 30,"SubmitDate":"2019-10-04"},{....},{....}]
```

I need it to be a List     `dataList -> Count 3`

first Item:

```
Age 30
FirstName "Yaniv"
LastName "Test"
SubmitDate [2019-10-04]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Producing excel from JSON input by `LoadFromCollection` was a bad idea.

The simplest and easiest solution is `LoadFromDataTable` by convert the JSON to a **DataTable**:

1. `DataTable data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(dataJson);`
2. `workSheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromDataTable(data,true);`

Simple as that

Comment: Probably there's no way to convert JSON to collection without declaring a static structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could deserialise your JSON into a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`. For example:

```
var json = "[{\"FirstName\":\"Yaniv\",\"LastName\":\"Test\",\"Age\": ......]"; 
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(json);
```

Now you can extract some details from this list. So to get the column names:

```
var columnNames = data.First().Keys.ToList();
```

And loop around your data like this. This will basically output in CSV format, but it should be enough to modify for your needs:

```
// Write out the column headers
foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
{
    Console.Write(columnName + ",");
}
Console.WriteLine();

// Write out each element
foreach (var item in data)
{
    foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
    {
        Console.Write(item[columnName] + ",");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

This will give output something like this:

```
FirstName,LastName,Age,SubmitDate,
Yaniv,Test,30,2019-10-04,
Yaniv,Test,30,2019-10-04,
Yaniv,Test,30,2019-10-04,
```

Comment: You don't need to deserialize it to list of dictionary of objects. All of these conversions are already handled by Newtonsoft.Json itself.

Comment: @Vyacheslav OK, this is still Newtonsoft doing the deserialisation, and doing it in a far more type-safe way than your method. It's also very clear for oher readers of the code what is expected, whereas using a `JArray` is not. Also, your method requires you to know the type of the property beforehand, which OP clearly says is not known. Is my answer wrong?

Comment: Yes. It is wrong. 1st - `JArray` itself acts like a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` (because JObject inherits `IDictionary<string, JToken>`); 2nd - it's harder to access property names (aka "columns"). You can do it easily in my solution and you have to access other array by index to get property name; 3rd - you can't properly deconstruct object that contained within the object. If it will happen - you'll have to cast object back to JProperty and go through underlying properties. In my solution - everything is already converted to the type `Newtonsoft.Json`'s developer intended to use.

Comment: 4th - you can determine field type by accessing `JProperty.Type` property and not blindly guess like in your solution (which was required by OP's needs). @DavidG

Comment: How is it *wrong* though? The code works, therefore, it must be correct.

Comment: I just explained that above. If your code works it doesn't mean that it's good. I can make thousands of examples of bad code. I mean it works, right?

Comment: No, you explained all about your solution, but, if it makes you happy, then you can use your version instead. I know which I prefer, and I'm experienced enough to know the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Newtonsoft.Json you can deserialize it into a dynamic structure:

```
var dyn = JArray.Parse("{jsonhere...}");
```

Then you can read properties like that:

```
const string json =
"[{\"prop\": 1, \"test\": \"test!\"}, {\"prop\": 2, \"test\": \"test again!\"}, {\"prop\": 3, \"test\": \"one more!\"}]";

var parsed = JArray.Parse(json);

foreach (var value in parsed)
{
     var prop = value.Value<int>("prop");
     var test = value.Value<string>("test");

     Console.WriteLine($"Prop: [{prop}] | Test: [{test}]");
}
```

Result output will be:

```
Prop: [1] | Test: [test!]
Prop: [2] | Test: [test again!]
Prop: [3] | Test: [one more!]
```